# parsing command line arguments with NSIS FileFunc.nsh gets incorrect values

Tags: windows, command-line-arguments, nsis

I have an NSIS script that contains this code for parsing a command line parameter called "GUID":

```
!include FileFunc.nsh
...
${GetParameters} $R0
ClearErrors
${GetOptions} $R0 '/GUID=' $guid
```

The value that it's trying to parse is a GUID: a 16-digit hex number, with hypens that separate each block of 4 characters.  So the command line looks something like this:

```
myprogram.exe /S /GUID=8a97-7c4f-09b7-a856-96e3
```

The problem is that this code returns a somewhat random-looking value that is not the guid value from the command line.  I did some experimentation and determined that the argument can be parsed if I pass in a pure integer, but value is wrong if the command line argument contains hypens or letters.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce this with NSIS v2.46:

```
!include FileFunc.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
var guid

Section
${GetParameters} $R0
ClearErrors
${GetOptions} $R0 '/GUID=' $guid
${If} ${Errors}
        ExecWait '"$exepath" /S /GUID=8a97-7c4f-09b7-a856-96e3'
${Else}
        Messagebox mb_ok |$guid|
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

Comment: It seems that this might be related to UAC. Apparently, an installer running with elevated permissions using the UAC plugin will not be executed with command line parameters.  Is that the case?  If so, is there a workaround?